# How to detect and implement wireless drivers on Gateway MX6446 Laptop?

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I recently installed Ubuntu on my friend's laptop because Windows wasn't running well, but the wireless hardware may not be detected, or I may not have the appropriate drivers(?). I tried [these instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214110) but it didn't seem to have any effect after rebooting. Let me know what additional information might help to figure out what's wrong.

EDIT:
`lspci -nn | grep 0280
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)`

[image]
sudo modprobe b43 dmesg | grep -e wlan -e b43 has given no response. I recently restarted after what's been done; there's no noticeable change. Rfkill list also gives no output.

```
firmware-b43-installer is already the newest version.
```

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) tutorial, and an answer in it revealed this output related to the blacklist:

```
b43-fwcutter is already the newest version.
b43-fwcutter set to manually installed.
firmware-b43-installer is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
timmy@timmy-MX6446:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/* | egrep 'bcm'
blacklist bcm43xx
timmy@timmy-MX6446:~$ # blacklist bcm43xx
timmy@timmy-MX6446:~$ sudo gedit blacklist.conf

** (gedit:3368): WARNING **: Can't load fallback CSS resource: Failed to import: The resource at '/org/gnome/adwaita/gtk-fallback.css' does not exist

** (gedit:3368): WARNING **: Can't load fallback CSS resource: Failed to import: The resource at '/org/gnome/adwaita/gtk-fallback.css' does not exist

(gedit:3368): Gt-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

Not sure if that helps at all. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Those instructions are correct if you have a Broadcom wireless device only. Let's confirm what you have. Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run: `lspci -nn | grep 0280`. Please edit your question to add the result and we'll propose a solution. Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: I'm afraid I'll be little help in answering this, but editing your question to include the output of `lspci -nn` and the model of the wireless card will help others to suggest answers for your issue.

Comment: I prefer `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`. This way current driver can be seen.

Comment: OK. You have wl installed already. I will update my answer.

Comment: Did you reboot after you purged bcmwl? The missing Radeon firmware is another issue but not significant to your Broadcom wireless.

Comment: I believe so, but I'll do it again and restart after. I purged again and it wasn't there to begin with. I restarted between the last time I purged and now.

Comment: @EllieZaffle Please do not post pictures, just copy text from terminal.

Comment: I did that hoping it would be better formatted than plain text, sorry.

Comment: Plain text is formatted well if you select it and press { } button.

Comment: @EllieZaffle You have to be connected to internet when run `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`. You need to connect some alternative way.

Comment: I'm connected via ethernet. I'll unplug, restart and try the command again.

Comment: You have to be plugged when install. And also give output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: I understand, I would just do it to restart the connection. I'm going to try after apt-get upgrade finishes.

Comment: @EllieZaffle And try my sequence of commands. wl should be removed before install of b43.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved through [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) guide and following it with `cat /etc/modprobe.d/* | egrep 'bcm'` then `cd /etc/modprobe.d/` , `sudo gedit blacklist.conf` and placing a `#` in front of blacklist bcm43xx, as according to KiLLeRfriend. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Your Broadcom device requires non-free firmware to work correctly. If you followed the instructions you linked and installed `firmware-b43-installer` and rebooted, your wireless should be working. If it is not, I suggest you check the wireless switch or key combination. You can see if the device is being turned off by the switch with:

```
rfkill list all
```

If there is no hard- or soft-block, check the logs for clues; first load the driver and look for any errors or warnings:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe b43
dmesg | grep -e wlan -e b43
```

Once I have more information, I will edit this answer to suggest a solution.

Comment: Neither of those output anything, and there is no physical wireless switch as far as I can tell. Does it log somewhere else? The key binding Fn + F2 (wireless switch) has no noticeable effect.

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Answer (score 0):

If wl driver does not work well for you, you can install b43.

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo modprobe -r wl
sudo modprobe b43
```

You need to uninstall wl driver because it blacklists b43.

Comment: `bcmwl-kernel-source` will not work with 14e4:4311 no matter what Broadcom says.

Comment: Are you sure? That used to be true. But it deserves testing.

Comment: I can PM you a dozen examples if you wish.

Comment: With last version of wl?

Comment: Certainly can with _every_ version of `wl`. I strongly suspect that her wireless isn't working because she already installed wl  and it has b43 blacklisted, in fact.

Comment: OK. Then b43 is always an option. Let's see.

Comment: @chili555 It look like you are correct.

Comment: I tried this, and the instructions above, with no luck, and no output for sudo modprobe b43. (Assuming it doesn't take several minutes) Upon trying these instructions, [sudo modprove -r wl] responded with [modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.]

Comment: @EllieZaffle It is not supposed to give output. I asked to give output of `rfkill list` 2 times and chili555 also once.

Comment: rfkill list also gives no output.